# use of fragments in android design

Tags: android, button, user-interface, android-fragments

I want to create an user interface similar to the following image. I have no idea to align the buttons to the screen. I am wondering whether I am supposed to create fragments.

[image: android screen sample]

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve what you need. You don't have to create fragments. RelativeLayout with a couple of ImageButtons will be enough.

Comment: The decision to use fragments is orthogonal to the layout design for a 3x2 grid of buttons.

Comment: Check my answer,but you can used relative layout but it's little bit crazy when editing elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.47" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.47" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can adjust margin and padding according to your requirement.